# Made this vBulletin Forum years ago, now it's spamming me errors

Tags: mysql, vbulletin

So I made this vBulletin forum years ago and several months ago it started emailing me errors every now and then. Since I registered as the forum administrator when I was creating the site, it now sends me emails when there are bugs. The site owner and I have got together and tried to remove every mention of my email from his site. I didn't think much of it but it persisted. I emailed the site owner about it and he mentioned he switched hosting companies but other than that no big changes.

Last night I got **60+** bug reports from this forum. I tried to ask on vBulletin's official forum but you have to have a license and such to use it.

Long story short, I hate vBulletin. I hate it so badly.

Can anyone help me with this error?

```
Database error in vBulletin :

mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111
/home/drumline/public_html/forum/includes/class_core.php on line 317

MySQL Error   :
Error Number  :
Request Date  : Tuesday, October 22nd 2013 @ 06:25:41 AM
Error Date    : Tuesday, October 22nd 2013 @ 06:25:41 AM
Script        : http://www.***.com/forum/showthread.php?162-Negative-Parents-how-to-convince-them-drumline-isn-t-evil&p=870&viewfull=1
Referrer      :
IP Address    : ***.**.*.***
Username      :
Classname     : vB_Database
MySQL Version :
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not a bug report, but an error report. The error message tells

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

The most probably case for this is that sometimes the MySQL server times out / doesn't respond in time and PHP stops waiting. Probably an issue of high load on your site.

> [...] he mentioned he switched hosting companies [...]

This somewhat confirms my suspicions.

Comment: I should've mentioned it's a plethora of various errors - not just the 'reading initial communication packet' one.

Comment: You shouldn't only have mentioned this, but list them. They're very probably very important in fixing your issues. Anyway, this will be probably off topic on Stackoverflow as it's not about development but administration and should better go to Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with it being better suited on Server Fault. If you've got access to the `my.cnf` file try increasing the `wait_timeout` by 60 seconds.